# Example of a boolean function

Tags: complexity-theory, boolean-algebra

Is there an example of real polynomial representation of a Boolean function with $4$ variables whose polynomial degree is $2$ that depends on $4$ variables?

Comment: $a\text{ and }b \:\: \text{ xor } \:\: c\text{ and }d \;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: $a\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}b \; + \; c\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}d \;\;\;\;$

Comment: $a=b=c=d=1$ gives $2$ as value. This cannot be right as Boolean function have $0/1$ value.

Comment: [GF(2)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteField.html) $\;$

Comment: Corrected question to real polynomial.

Comment: What does this have to do with complexity theory or boolean algebra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Using the convention that inputs and outputs are $\pm 1$, then the function is
$$
\frac{a(x+y)+b(x-y)}{2}.
$$
You could have found this function using exhaustive search – there are only $2^{16}$ functions on $4$ variables.

Comment: Is there a computer program which does this trick?

Comment: Yes, a computer program which you write. I actually wrote it once, which is how I found this function in the first place.

Comment: Interesting so some examples could be found by brute force.